# Virtual Machine from Azure marketplace image with terraform script having an error

Tags: azure, terraform

I am new to Azure . I am using terraform to deploy Azure the virtual machines from marketplace images.
I have written the code but getting an error.

```
  resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "virtualmachine" {
  name                  = "virtualmachine01"
  location              = "centralus"
  resource_group_name   = "xyz"
  network_interface_ids = [azurerm_network_interface.nics.id]
  vm_size               = "Standard_F2"

source_image_reference {
    publisher = "cloudeteer"
    offer     = "cdt_cloud-ops"
    plan       = "cloud_pro"
    version   = "latest"
  }

 tags = module.tags.tags_output
# Creating a Virtual network interface 
esource "azurerm_network_interface" "nics01" {
   name                        = "nicsexample"
   location                    = var.location
   resource_group_name         = "rg"
   tags                        = module.tags.tags_output
   ip_configuration {
       name                          = "ipconfigexample"
       subnet_id                     = "id"
       private_ip_address_allocation = "static"
       private_ip_address            = var.vm1_private_ip_address
       
   }
}
}
```

Error: Unsupported block type

on virtual_machine.tf line 21, in resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "virtualmachine":
21: source_image_reference {

Blocks of type "source_image_reference" are not expected here.

Can anyone please help.

Answer (score 1):

`source_image_reference` is part of [azurerm_linux_virtual_machine](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/linux_virtual_machine), not `azurerm_virtual_machine`.

Thus you have to **change `virtualmachine` resource type**, and probably adjust other attributes if there are differences between them.

Answer (score 0):

That's right, source_image_reference is part of azurerm_linux_virtual_machine, not azurerm_virtual_machine. so you will have to change the attriute.

And it depends what type of marketplace you are using. If it's related to windows , you can use "Storage image reference" and doesn't require plan id under it, because it will give you an error. you can add SKU details and try to create

```
source_image_reference {
  publisher = "cloudeteer"
  offer     = "cdt_cloud-ops"
  sku       = "cloud_pro"
  version   = "latest"
```

}

Also add PLAN Block

```
plan{
  name = "cloude"
  product = "cloudeteer"
  publisher = "cloudeteer"
}
```

Rest of the code looks fine for me.